# Multiple toolbar buttons with Google Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I've recently installed Google Plugin over my Eclipse 4.2, and now I've got a problem with my toolbar buttons. Those added by plugin are multiplied, now I have 2 sets, but my older eclipse installation on other machine has about 8 of them, and thats pretty annoying.

Can anyone help me find what causes this problem?[image: MUltiple toolbar buttons]

**Edit:**
I cannot remove extra buttons via Window->Customize perspective...->Tool Bar Visibility (unselecting GDTPulldownToolbar group or any of its child). Unchecking extra items does nothing, and no errors are outputted to Eclipse Error Log view. I'll be happy if I could remove all Google Plugin buttons from my toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to **Window > Customize Perspective > Tool Bar Visibility**

You will see : **"GDT PulldownToolbar"**

1. If its unchecked, re-check it. Click on "OK".
2. Now you will see the icons on tool bar.
3. Again goto same view i.e. "Tool Bar Visibility"
4. Un-check the **"GDT PulldownToolbar"**. Click on "OK".

With above steps, I was able to hide the repeating toolbars successfully. (Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819 : Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit, GWT plugin 4.3)

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, I confirm that redundant icons are gone. This type of workaround is sufficient for me, however the cause of the problem remains unidentified.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the steps you went through to install GPE, the best I can suggest is to do a fresh install of Juno, and then install GPE through the Help > Install New Software ... menu, pointing the Eclipse installer to the Juno GPE update site, https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2.

Of course if you're doing this, you might as well upgrade to Kepler, and point the updater to the Kepler GPE update site, https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3.