# Eclipse showing multiple Google Plugin button on the toolbar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse, google-app-engine

I had installed Google plugin for Eclipse about an year ago and everything was working fine until recently when I noticed a very peculiar behaviour of the plugin that it's increasing the number of icons it displays on the toolbar for the plugin by one everytime I restart my eclipse. I looked for a solution on stackoverflow and found a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125251/multiple-toolbar-buttons-with-google-plugin-for-eclipse) but the solution did not work for me.

Not sure what is wrong here, also the dropdown options for the plugin is repeatedly increasing with every restart.

I'm using :

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Build id: 20140224-0627

Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3

[image]